# Spring Integration Async Gateway with error-channel causes threads to park

Tags: spring-integration, asynchronous

I have an async gateway with an async executor and an error-channel defined. Also there is a service activator that handles exceptions.

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway"
             service-interface="me.myGateway"
             default-request-channel="requestChannel"
             async-executor="taskScheduler"
             error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<int:service-activator ref="errorChannelMessageHandler" method="handleFailedInvocation"
                       input-channel="errorChannel"/>
```

```
public interface MyGateway {
    Future<Object> send(Message message);
}

@Component
public class ErrorChannelMessageHandler {
    @ServiceActivator
    public Object handleFailedInvocation(MessagingException exception) {
        // do some stuff here
        return null;
    }
}
```

When an exception is being thrown, the thread blocks, waiting for a reply on the temporary reply channel the gateway has created.

How can I prevent the threads from blocking and when exceptions are thrown to have the error-channel service activator handle the message and perform some custom logic?

Later edit:
I am using SI 3.0.3.RELEASE
When an error channel is defined for the gateway, if exception occurs it will call this line (no 250 from MessagingGatewaySupport) *errorFlowReply = this.messagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(this.errorChannel, errorMessage)*, which will do a blocking receive on a newly created temporary reply channel(lines 352-367 from MessagingTemplate). Is my service activator for the error-channel responsible for publishing a message on this newly create temporary channel, so the thread won't block on the receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the error-channel so that the original exception is added to the `Future` so that the `get()` will propagate it.

If you want to do something on the error flow, throw an exception from the error flow so it's available in the `Future`, or set `reply-timeout` to 0. However, your Future will never get a value or exception in that case.

Comment: Long story short: My SI chain connects to RabbitMQ and posts messages. When rabbit connection is down, AmqpConnectException will be thrown. What I want to do in this case is to get the messages and persist them somewhere (db, local files). This is where the error channel is usefull, because in a service activator I will do this action. If I remove the error channel, how can I do this? The get() on the Future might not always be called, because sometimes I want an answer, sometimes I just do fire-and-forget.

Comment: And another question: If I remove the error-channel, then what's the point of having this attribute for a gateway if I can't use it properly? Or I am missing something here. Thanks

Comment: You can use an error channel, but the error flow has to return a result or throw an exception (or as I said, set the `reply-timeout` to 0). It won't affect "good" flows unless you have further async handoffs - the reply timeout only starts when the thread returns to the gateway.

Comment: The MessagingTemplate will still create a temp reply channel and will block in the receive. I can't see how this will work without a reply-timeout. How can the error flow return a result or throw an exception?

Comment: How about this? `@ Component
public class ErrorChannelMessageHandler {
    @ ServiceActivator
    public void handleFailedInvocation(Message<MessagingException> message) {
       //persist the message.getPayload().getFailedMessage(); 
       MessageChannel replyChannel = (MessageChannel) message.getHeaders().get("replyChannel");
       CustomResponse customResponse = new CustomResponse(...);          replyChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(customResponse).build());
    }
}`I send a response to the gateway and the future will always return a response and I can customize the response

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format my code to look better here in stackoverflow

Comment: You don't need to send to the `replyChannel` directly; just have your method return some value (instead of `void`) and the framework will take care of things. When posting code, edit your question instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussel. I just tried this on a sample project and it works by returning something in my error handler. I believe I also tried this on the project I am working on and it didn't work, but I will give it a try tomorrow. Thanks again for your patience.